# Phonegap - Creating a .txt file on first load

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, createfile

I am creating a phonegap app and need to create a new .txt file on first load. After this I need to check whether the file exists and then ignore the creation if that is the case, below is the general flow that I am after:

1 - onDeviceReady - loading phoengap app
2 - Check is readme.txt exist (if yes load home page)
3 - Create a file readme.txt and add to www folder
4 - Continue loading homepage

EDIT - Rather than the valid answer mentioned below I decided to use HTML5s local storage as this was simply 1 line of code.

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Email Supplied!");
```

and can be checked using this simple if statement

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("name") == "Email Supplied!")
        {
            // What you want to happen here
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the full example here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

This line create the file if it doesn't exist :

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

> > Supported Platforms
>
> Android BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher) iOS Windows Phone 7 (
>   Mango )

I don't know about there others but in iOS, the document is created in /var/mobile/Application/YOU_APP/Documents

[CODE]

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
            }

            function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
            }

            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            }

            function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                    console.log("write success");
                };

                writer.write("some sample text");
                writer.abort();
                // contents of file now 'some different text'
            }

            function fail(error) {
                console.log("error : "+error.code);
            }

        </script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that and nothing seemed to get created, maybe I was looking int he wrong location for the file. Do you know where the file is saved upon creation and whether you can set where you want it to be saved? Thanks

Comment: Also will this work for all of Android, iOS and Blackberry (mainly iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the devices you are developing for you can look at using their native file creation APIs. For example, iOS uses plists. Android does use .txt files, look at this [link](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html) for more information.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials that you can point me towards for the iOS implementation? Thanks

Comment: If you use native file creation API, you are going to need as many plugins as OS you are developing on since PhoneGap need to join these API.