# DevExpress - DevExtreme How to create File

Tags: cordova, devexpress, phonejs, devextreme

I'm developing a project with DevExtreme.

I want to create a file.

How can I do it with DevExtreme ?

PhoneGap is being done with, I could not find examples. How can I do.  - DevExtreme but want to do it. please help

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [standard PhoneGap features](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) for this purpose. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462668/) SO thread to find an example.